# Find files with user specified extensions

Tags: find, ksh

I am writing a script that takes multiple file extensions as a comma separated string and use it to list files within a specific directory structure, but the number of extensions provided may vary.

The find command I am using is

```
     find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.ksh -o -iname \*.cfg \)
```

Here the user is searching for ksh and cfg files. But the user may find only ksh , or cfg or many more extensions as well. Is there a way to make the search pattern generic for any number of extensions?

Comment: Would it be ok to choose to pass the filename suffixes as a list of arguments instead of as a comma-delimited string? It would otherwise be difficult to handle suffixes that contain commas, as in `code.c,v` (a file in a CVS repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you get the filename suffixes as separate command line arguments (see end of answer for how to deal with a comma-delimited string instead):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for suffix do
    set -- "$@" -o -iname "*.$suffix"
    shift
done

shift

find . -type f \( "$@" \)
```

This script wold be called as

```
./script.sh ksh cfg
```

and it would replace each suffix `$suffix` in the positional parameters with `-o -iname "*.$suffix"`.

The lone `shift` before the call to `find` removes the initial `-o` in `"$@"`.

Using arrays in `ksh93` or `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh

name_opts=()

for suffix do
    name_opts+=( -o -iname "*.$suffix" )
done

find . -type f \( "${name_opts[@]:1}" \)
```

The `:1` in `"${name_opts[@]:1}"` discards the first element of the `name_opts` array (the initial `-o`).

---

If you really want to get the suffixes as a comma-delimited string (which means you can't use the script to look for files with commas in their filename suffixes, such as files in RCS or CVS storage), you can convert that string, `$list`, to an array in `bash` or `ksh93` with

```
set -f
suffixes=( ${list//,/ } )
set +f
```

or in `sh` with

```
set -f
set -- $( printf '%s\n' "$list" | tr ',' ' ' )
set +f
```

or

```
set -f; ifs=$IFS; IFS=','
set -- $list
set +f; IFS=$ifs; unset ifs
```

(these set the positional parameters to the list of suffixes).

The `set -f` turns off filename generation (globbing) since we rely on the shell to split the string on the spaces that we replace the commas by, but to *not* use the generated words for globbing. Without `set -f` we would not be able to correctly handle a request for suffixes like `[ch]` or `*`.

The loop in `bash` or `ksh` would then change from

```
for suffix do ...
```

to

```
for suffix in "${suffixes[@]}"; do ...
```

while the loop in `sh` would remain as is.

Comment: Thanks, but file extension aren't the only argument provided to the script. To be honest, the file extension string comes as the 3rd positional argument

Comment: @KumarjitGhosh Then you should also read the second half of my answer.

Comment: Almost good: do not use `for suffix do`, the autoconf texinfo documentation warns off it. Use `for suffix in "$@"; do` (preferred) or `for suffix` + newline(! not semicolon!) + `do` instead.

Comment: @mirabilos It warns against that because the original Bourne shell did not support it. I'm using that syntax though since I've noticed that people tend to leave off the quotes around `$@` if I didn't (not realising they make a difference). I've also not seen a shell in a while that does not support that POSIX standard syntax.

Comment: Even then, it shoul use `"$@"`, if alone for consistency with uses outside of `for`.

Comment: @mirabilos Yes, that's what I'm saying. When I've seen people reuse shell code from here with loops with `"$@"`, they sometimes leave the quotes out, which is wrong. Better then to use the syntax that doesn't even mention `"$@"` at all. Less risk for confusion that way.

Comment: Second option worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-iregex` instead of multiple `-iname`s.  e.g. using extended regular expressions:

GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -iregex '.*\.(ksh|cfg)$'
```

FreeBSD `find`:

```
find -E  . -type f -iregex '.*\.(ksh|cfg)$'
```

If you already have the extensions comma-separated in a variable (e.g. `$csep`), convert them to regexp alternations (`|`). first.  e.g

```
csep='ksh,sh,cfg,csv'
re="$(echo "$csep" | tr , '|')"
find . -type f -regextype egrep -iregex ".*\.($re)$"
#BSD: find -E . -type f -iregex ".*\.($re)$"
```

If you needed to support extensions with commas in them, you could use `sed` instead of `tr`, to allow for backslash-escaped commas (`\,`). e.g.

```
$ csep='ksh,sh,cfg,csv,c\,v'
$ re="$(echo "$csep" | sed -Ee 's/([^\]),/\1|/g')"
$ printf '%b\n' "$re"
ksh|sh|cfg|csv|c\,v
```

Comment: Got an error -E is not a valid option

Comment: are you running freebsd? or something else using freebsd's version of find?  if so, what version?  From `man find` on FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p10: `-E      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).` and `The -E option was inspired by the equivalent grep(1) and sed(1) options.`.  Also, it worked when I tested it on my freebsd VM.